# Kafka JDBC source not showing numeric values

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am deploying a Kafka Connect JDBC Source. It is connecting properly to the dabase, but the result I am getting is this:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "bytes",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "version": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "scale": "0"
        },
        "field": "ID"
      },
      {
        "type": "bytes",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "version": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "scale": "0"
        },
        "field": "TENANT_ID"
      },
      {
        "type": "bytes",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "version": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "scale": "0"
        },
        "field": "IS_ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "CREATION_DATE"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": true,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "LAST_LOGIN"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "NAME"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "MOBILEPHONE"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "EMAIL"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "USERNAME"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "PASSWORD"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "EXTERNAL_ID"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false
  },
  "payload": {
    "ID": "fdo=",
    "TENANT_ID": "Uw==",
    "IS_ACTIVE": "AQ==",
    "CREATION_DATE": 1548987456000,
    "LAST_LOGIN": 1557401837030,
    "NAME": " ",
    "MOBILEPHONE": " ",
    "EMAIL": " ",
    "USERNAME": "ES00613751",
    "PASSWORD": " ",
    "EXTERNAL_ID": " "
  }
}
```

As you can see, the numeric and timestamp values are not showing the value properly.

The config:

```
name=jdbc-teradata-source-connector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=...
numeric.maping=best_fit
topic.prefix=test-2
mode=timestamp+incrementing
timestamp.column.name=LAST_LOGIN
incrementing.column.name=ID

topic=test-jdbc-oracle-source
```

The numeric mapping does not work since it is Confluent 3.2.2
I have also tried to cast the numbers to numeric but it does not work either.

Comment: Add your connector configuration

Comment: What's your source table DDL? This article should help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#bytes-decimals-numerics

Comment: @Robin Moffatt I have updated the question

Comment: @A.Gisbert I don't see the DDL in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your connector config numeric.mapping

```
"numeric.mapping":"best_fit"
```

you can see all explication [here](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/7bb46a0b6d27982a5fb7a103bb7c95b9)

Comment: Please add a brief description on why you think `numeric.mapping` is the parameter to add. Just giving them a configuration to try without the background information is not optimal